# Can keydown be use in different sections of a web page using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have the following content,

```html
<div id="sectionA"></div>
<div id="sectionB"></div>
<div id="sectionC"></div>
```

```js
$("#sectionA").bind(keydown, function(events)
{
    alert("section A");
    return false;
});

$("#sectionB").bind(keydown, function(events)
{
    alert("section B");
    return false;
});

$("#sectionA").bind(keydown, function(events)
{
    alert("section C");
    return false;
});
```

Is this possible, and if not, how can I get this to work?

Comment: My goal is to have keydown work in different parts of the web application.

Comment: You to change keydown by "keydown" (quotes missing) and likely the last selector is `"#sectionC"` and not `#sectionA`

Comment: Remember that `contenteditable` is HTML5, hope this is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work on items that can have focus. You can make them `contenteditable`, or as Marc mentioned, give them a `tabindex` and it will work.

You also want to make sure you're referencing the event as a string, not as a variable:

```
$("#sectionA").bind(keydown, function(events)
```

should be

```
$("#sectionA").bind('keydown', function(events)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5upvR/

Comment: This is true, additionally anything that has a `tabindex` attribute. See this for an example of the tabindex: http://jsfiddle.net/2d3xv/ There's some downsides to both, however.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach Add `tabindex="0"` to the 3 of them, I don't see any downside besides adding a couple items more in the tabbing.

Comment: Thanks for understanding the question and solution.

Comment: He needs also to change `keydown` by `"keydown"` (quotes missing)

Comment: The downside there is that they become selectable now (Mouse or tab - at least on Chrome). That could be a negative UI experience, but it certainly depends on the application. `contenteditable` has a slightly more obvious downside, but only on browsers that support it.

Comment: Yep! only forget to change the last selector from sectionA to sectionC otherwise the message doesn't make sense

Comment: I doubt that's a downside for this use case Marc, as it would likely be a requirement for the user to know where they are for the keydown event to make sense for them - and if not, some simple CSS will remove those browser highlights on focus.

Comment: The tabindex trick works in all modern browsers and even older ones such as IE6; you can remove the focus outline in Chrome with `outline:none;` CSS but as AlienWebguy said, there should be some visible indication for the user.